# AWS SES emails are not sent to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, amazon-ses

I’ve done the following steps to configure SES, S3, and IAM users for SES.

1. Via SES in the us-east-1 region, verified sampledomain.com and added
   CNAME, MX, and TXT records in Route 53. (Making sure that MX (10
   inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com) applies for sampledomain.com
2. Set email receiving rule, set noreply@sampledomain.com as a
   recipient email and the action is set to “Deliver to Amazon S3
   bucket” (created S3 bucket upon adding the rule and it’s in the same
   region – us-east-1)
3. Added noreply@sampledomain.com in the verified
   entities list
4. Created email credentials for SES with default rights
5. Requested AWS to grant the production access and now it’s already in
   production mode
6. Tried to send the email from
   noreply@sampledomain.com to xxx@gmail.com and vice versa. It’s okay to send without any errors in the AWS console and well-received via xxx@gmail.com

The only issue is that there’s no incoming email in the S3 bucket (except the two emails - AMAZON_SES_SETUP_NOTIFICATION and another email to verify the email address- noreply@sampledomain.com)

Please let me know if there’s a step that is missing or how I should troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: The receiving rule is for emails send to noreply@sampledomain.com. You are sending the email from noreply@sampledomain.com to xxx@gmail.com. Those will not get captured into S3. If you want to test your receiving rule that writes to S3 try sending an email from xxx@gmail.com to noreply@sampledomain.com.

Comment: @TobievanderMerwe Thanks for your reply. Actually, I sent several emails from xxx@gmail.com to noreply@sampledomain.com as well and forgot to mention it in the description. I'll add it in the description and thanks for your reply again.

Comment: Any resolution to this my issue is identical every single step you described? The receiving emails portion of aws ses is done extremely poorly.